# Is the subspace of an eigenspace invariant?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\phi$ be a diagonalizable endomorphism. Let $E_{\lambda}$ be an associated eigenspace and $F_{\lambda}$ is a subspace of $E_{\lambda}$, that is $F_{\lambda}  \subset E_{\lambda}$.

Is $F_{\lambda}$ $\phi$-invariant?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @Chrystomath I think it is. By extracting vectors from a basis of $E_{\lambda}$ to form $F_{\lambda}$, $F_{\lambda}$ must be $\phi$-invariant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $E_\lambda$ is an eigenspace of $\phi$ associated to an eigenvalue $\lambda$, then (by definition), $\phi(v)=\lambda v$ for all $v\in E_\lambda$.  So if $F_\lambda\subset E_\lambda$ is a subspace, then for all $u\in F_\lambda$, we have $\phi(u)=\lambda u\in F_\lambda$. Hence, $\phi(F_\lambda)\subset F_\lambda$.  So $F_\lambda$ is $\phi$-invariant.